# how to have multiple values in every entry of an array using jquery

Tags: jquery, angularjs

This is a code I have to display a list using AngularJs:

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<body>

<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="namesCtrl">

<ul>
  <li ng-repeat="x in names">
    {{ x.name + ', ' + x.country }}
  </li>
</ul>

</div>

<script>
angular.module('myApp', []).controller('namesCtrl', function($scope) {
    $scope.names = [
        {name:'Jani',country:'Norway'},
        {name:'Hege',country:'Sweden'},
        {name:'Kai',country:'Denmark'}
    ];
});
</script>

</body>
```

which shows the following output:

[image: output]

how do I get the above output using JQuery?

Comment: Welcome to SO. You should probably try first before asking plainly for an answer. Show us what you did so we can help you improve/correct it.

Answer (score 0):

```
// Jquery reference here


 <body >
        <ul id = "countryList" ></ul>
    < script >
          var names = {name: 'Jani',country: 'Norway'},
            {name: 'Hege', country: 'Sweden'},
            {name: 'Kai',country: 'Denmark' }

    $.each(names, function(k, v) {
        $("#countryList").append("<li>" + v.name + "</li>")
        }); 
</script>    
        </body>
```